# Will a lid hovering above bursting air bubbles catch smog particles

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, design, pressure

[image]

The bubble bursting phenomenon goes like the above describes:

At 1, the air bubble is under water.

At 2, the bubble emerges above the surface, with a thin film of water rising to keep it from bursting.

At 3, the bubble is about to burst, and the pink coloured part of the water film will form an aerosol of micron sized water film droplets in STEP 4.

At 4, the bubble bursts and the water film forms aerosol.

Now I consider smog air, with PM2.5 particles. How does the mechanism work for the smog particles? I thought it might go like so:

[image]

The same as previously described, except now, there are the smog particles in the bubble (this shows as brown dots in the bubble in diagram).

So now, upon bursting, the air molecules AND the smog particles escape the surface. Now particles would probably be shot up at very high speeds, just like the film droplets (which shoot up at an initial velocity of around 1 m/s). If so, and given that smog particles are sticky, they should stick to the lid hovering above the water surface? As for the air, as it is molecules and MUCH smaller, it simply escapes from the sides.

Why not use this as an air purifier system if it works ;)

EDIT 1: I'm laughing knowing I NEED to point this out to engineers, but by smog particles, I don't mean acidic gas MOLECULES, because I would have simple said that. I mean the soot and carbon PM2.5 particles that make a healthy man equal to a chain smoker simply by existing.

EDIT 2: To all those offending me by calling me names and stuff, here is something to show that your knowledge ain't encompassing. General remark, not pointing to anyone. They know themselves better.

https://www.bu.edu/articles/2023/new-bubble-popping-theory-could-help-track-ocean-pollution-and-viruses/

Comment: @Fred It seems irrelevant here. It doesn't facilitate smoke particle capture by design.

Answer (score 0):

If your reasoning is that the air molecules are much smaller and simply escape from the sides, then you could just have a lid with a bunch of very small openings in it...which is what a filter is. So for this reasoning to work, you would need a lid with a gap as small as that in a HEPA filter, which is quite impractical.

Now, I do not know if smog particles would stick to your lid, but suppose they do. A smooth lid has a very small amount of surface area to begin with which does not give a lot of space for smog particles to adhere (if they stick to it at all). Again, this is a problem solved by the fibrous nature of a HEPA filter, as well as charcoal filters.

Comment: @ElFlea where does DKNguyen limit the answer to acidic gas molecules?

Comment: @SolarMike Neither do I claim so.

Comment: The whole point of me experimenting is to find an alternative to the expensive HEPA filters and their constant need of being replaced. The air here is so awful with smog that you can't see things a two meters away sometimes. 480 AQI.

Comment: @ElFlea Well a lid being separated by a <0.3 micron gap would be far more expensive than any HEPA filter while providing nearly zero through-flow. HEPA filters also don't really lose filtration capability as they wear out. They actually filter better but they will pass less air through them as they clog up so you can push a HEPA filter quite far depending on what kind of throughflow you are willing to put up with. Much cheaper pre-filters that are replaced more frequently also used to deal with larger, more easily filtered particles to stretch the HEPA filter life.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well you have a point IF we indeed do need a <0.3 micron gap. The thing is, we probably don't, as the particles will be shot upwards at very high initial velocities and the droplets with them will make sure they stick to the surface due to being wet. Check my edit for a recent experiment that proves my point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds over complicated.
Smog is composed of nitrous, carbon monoxide, sulfates suspended in atmosphere, Real best way to get rid of it, is humidity.
Because these fine composites soluable in water.
Air humidifiers work well absorb nacent pollution, because gases and particulates stick to water molecules.

combustion Power plants spray mist water before exhausting. Some coal plants have coal delivered washed.

Since the bubbles are 99.99% air and 0.01 percent water, the surface area of the water grows over 1000x fold. But exposure requires a HUGE surface area for bubbles to effectively touch enough polluted air.

The best way to prevent smog is go after it's source, because the particles are molecular level, only a molecule filter like reverse osmosis for gas exchange will remove it. A HEPA filter may remove soot, particulates, but that's not SMOG, at least not the kind you're probably worrying about

Comment: I want to trap soot particles, not acidic gas molecules.